# How to copy non-consecutive cells and paste into non-consecutive cells

Tags: excel, excel-365, kofax

I've converted a Kofax PDF into excel365, but the formatting is off. I need to move the highlighted cells into the cell directly adjacent to them. There is other "junk" information in these columns (ie, the "reimb & other payments"), so it would likely be quicker to simply select the cells I need and paste them over (if this is possible)

[image]

Regular copy/pasting does not maintain the row number, the selection would be pasted into E1, E2, E3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick. E. g., you want copy cells from F to E. Put '=E6' formula into F6, then enable auto filter and select non-empty cells in E. The select F6 and fill down. Reset the filter. Finally select E, copy and paste values here in E.
[image]

To remove empty cells from E and preserve their order use this trick. Fill down any column with consecutive numbers like 1, 2, 3... (further the numeration column). Then sort a range including E and the numeration column by E. Empty cells in E will move to the end. Delete rows with empty cells then sort the range by the numeration column to restore the initial order. Clear the numeration column.